# Jenkins: Pass environment variable to the job parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables

Since I have the same `static` rarely changed parameters used by several jobs I decided to put it somewhere in one place of my Jenkins and use it across jobs.

The first thought that came to my mind was to move my 'static data' to the environment variables and get it using `Active choice reactive parameter` plugin which allows running simple groovy scripts on the job parameters page.

Please note that `I know how to get environment parameters in the pipeline`, but I do really need to have this data on the `build with parameters` screen, e.g. once I clicked `build with parameters` - I need my groovy code inside `Active choice reactive parameter` was able to read this environment variable and display as a parameter to the user.

A simple example of this need:
The environment variable contains the list of servers, the job is going to perform deployment of the application to the selected server. In this case, I want to be able to write something like this in the `groovy script` section of `Active choice reactive parameter`:

```
return[${env.SERVERS_LIST}]
```

Unfortunately the example above doesn't work. I wasn't able to find any working solution for this yet.

Comment: `${...}` is only used inside strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few more tries I finally found a solution.

Instead of trying to read the environment variable in the `pipeline manner` the simple

```
return [SERVERS_LIST]
```

works perfect

Comment: yes, pipeline dsl is for pipeline. just checked `System.getenv('ENV_VAR')` - works as well